# How to create method (function) in groovy with given params but not defined

Tags: groovy

I'm completly new to groovy, and to be honest I have real hard time with finding things in groovy. So i noticed that somethink like this can be achieve:

We have function

```
def static someMethod (params) {
...
}
```

and then you are able to call this one like this :

```
someMethod (param1 : value1, param2 : value2, param3 : value3....)
```

So my question is : how can I read those param1, param2 etc in my `someMethod`? I mean should I do something close to this ?

```
def static someMethod (params) {
def result = param1 + param2 + param3
}
```

And If someone let say dont give param3 will this function return nullPointerException?
Like I said I'm new, so any answer is probably best (some links meaby?)
Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When You declare such method:

```
def static someMethod (params) {
   def result = params.param1 + params.param2 + params.param3
   println result
}
```

and then invoke like this:

```
someMethod (param1 : 1, param2 : 2, param3 :3)
```

what You pass to method invocation is `map`, so in the method's body there's a need to prefix key names with map name in this case `params`.

When no value is present for key - `null` will be returned, unless You define a `map` using `withDefault` - then default value will be returned.

Comment: Ah i see thanks for an answer. One more question: so if its a map, i can first create some defaultMap and then load my params to this map using somethink like this: default << (params ? params : [:]) ?

Comment: You could have `params = [ param1:'a', param2:'b', param3:'c' ] << params` as the first line of the method...

Comment: One thing to watch out for when using this type of method is that they are hard to document, and the method signature doesn't give any hints as to what _magic_ params it can possibly take.  It's really good for things like xml builders, etc...  But in general, specifying the parameters might be a better self-documenting route?